# OpenGL ES 2.0 blending only on different objects

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I was wondering if there is a way to blend objects that are in different draw calls alone.

I have a particle system that draws many points close to each other and I don't want to add their color values. However I do want to add those particles with other particles from a different particle system draw call. I know I could achieve this using a frame buffer object but it doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible directly via blending; the only state GL has at any point in time is the current fragment, and the contents of the framebuffer.

You could imagine using a stencil mask (clear the stencil at the start of the draw, set the stencil to 1 with each triangle in the particle system, and fail if the stencil test if the value is already 1). However most particles need some level of alpha transparency to fade out each particle at the edges, so this is probably not what you actually want ...

Actually, given the need for the "fade" region of one particle to overlap the "bright" part of a particle behind it, I'm not entirely sure that you can make this work without blending all of the particles in the particle system together.

Comment: In my case I don't use a fade out effect for the particles (they just get smaller) so the stencil mask seems like it would work. Thanks!!